# Exercise 6.11 from Isaac's Character theory of finite groups.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, characters

I'm a noob in group theory, so please forgive me if I put some silly questions. I try to solve the following problem (6.11 from Isaac's book, Character theory of finite groups):

Let $A\unlhd G$ with $A$ Abelian. Let $\chi$ be an irreducible monomial character of $G$. Prove that $\chi$ is a relative monomial character with respect to $A$, i.e. there exists a subgroup $H$ with $A\subset H\subset G$ and an irreducible character $\psi$ of $H$ such that $\psi_A$ is irreducible and $\psi^G=\chi$.

Since $\chi$ is monomial, there exists a subgroup $K$ and a linear character $\lambda$ of $K$ such that $\chi=\lambda^G$. The hint given is that: Every constituent of $(\lambda^{AH})_A = (\lambda_{A\cap H})^A$ has multiplicity $1$. I don't know how to prove this hint and how to solve the problem using it. The linear character $\psi_A$ should be a constituent of $(\lambda^{AH})_A$? I don't grasp the connection between $\psi$ and $\lambda$. Ito's theorem (according to which $\chi(1)||G:A|$) plays a role in solving this problem?

Comment: About Ito's theorem. The converse is true? If $A\unlhd G$ is normal and for any irreducible charater $\chi$ of $G$, it holds that $\chi(1)| |G:A|$, this implies that $A$ is Abelian?

Comment: The hint does not make much sense. What is $H$ in the hint? Also is $\chi$ assumed to be irreducible?

Comment: The converse of Ito's Theorem is not true: take $G=Q_8 \times C_2$, where $Q_8$ is the quaternion group of order $8$. All irreducible characters have degree $1$ or $2$ and hence divide $|G:Q_8|=2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A \unlhd G$ and $\chi$ a monomial irreducible (complex) character say $\chi=\lambda^G$, with $\lambda$ linear character of a subgroup $K$ of $G$. Consider the subgroup $KA$. Observe that $\lambda^{KA}$ is irreducible. By using Problem (5.2) in Isaacs' book (all references are in *Character Theory of Finite Groups*), we have $(\lambda^{KA})_A=(\lambda_{K \cap A})^A$. Since $A$ is abelian, we can find a linear character $\mu$ of $A$, such that $\mu_{K \cap A}=\lambda_{K \cap A}$. Now apply (6.17) Corollary (Gallagher): we must have 
$$(\lambda^{KA})_A=(\lambda_{K \cap A})^A=\sum_{\nu \in Irr(A/K \cap A)} \mu \nu$$
Observe that all $\nu$ and hence $\mu\nu$ are linear, since $A$ is abelian. The corollary also says that all the $\mu\nu$ are *distinct* and are all of the irreducible constituents of $(\lambda_{K \cap A})^A$. Hence $(\lambda^{KA})_A$ is the sum of distinct conjugates of the $\mu$. Now apply Clifford's Theorem ((6.11) Theorem), there must be a *linear* character $\psi \in I_{KA}(\mu)$, the inertia group of $\mu$, with $[\psi_A,\mu] \neq 0$, such that $\psi^{KA}=\lambda^{KA}$. Hence $\chi=\lambda^G=(\lambda^{KA})^G=(\psi^{KA})^G=\psi^G$ by transitivity of induction (see Problem (5.1)). So $H=I_{KA}(\mu)$ is the requested subgroup.

Comment: I have just one small (maybe stupid) question: the fact that $\lambda^{AK}$ is irreducible is crucial in the proof?

Comment: Yes, good question, this is essential for the application of Clifford’s Theorem.

Comment: Ok, if I understood correctly, if $\lambda^{KA}$ would not be irreducible, then for any irreducible component $\theta$ of $\lambda^{KA}$ we can find $\psi$ on $H$ with $\psi^{KA}=\theta$.

Comment: Hmm, $\lambda^{KA}$ is irreducible because $\lambda^G=\chi$ is irreducible.

Comment: I know, but I wonder what can be said if one drop the hypothesis $\chi$ is irreducible and assume only that $\chi=\lambda^G$.

Comment: Also, there is something wrong with $[\psi_{K\cap A},\mu]\neq 0$, since $\mu$ is a character of $A$. I assume it should be $[\psi_{A},\mu]\neq 0$, but this means that $\psi_A=\mu$, since both characters are linear. I'm a little bit confused.

Comment: Yes corrected that, thanks! Indeed $\psi_A=\mu$, since Clifford's Theorem also gives you that $[(\lambda^{KA})_A,\mu]=[\psi_A,\mu]$. So $\psi$ is linear! Remember that $\mu$ only appears once in the sum formula above.

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand why $\psi$ is linear. Clifford's theorem says only that $\psi$ is irreducible on $H$. Also, if I'm not wrong, we have that $\psi^{KA}(1)=[KA:H]\psi(1)$, while $\lambda^{KA}(1)=[KA:K]$, hence $\psi(1)=[KA:H]/[KA:K]$.

Comment: I think I get it. $|KA:H|$ is the size of the orbit of $\mu$. On the other hand, the orbit of $\mu$ has the size $|KA:K|$, so $|KA:K|=|KA:H|$. In particular, $|K|=|H|\geq |A|$. Interesting...

Comment: Correct. Yes quite surprising that the orders of $H$ and $K$ are the same.

Answer (score 2):

There is a converse to Ito's Theorem that runs as follows.

**Proposition** Let $N$ be a normal Hall subgroup of $G$ and assume that $\chi(1) \mid |G:N|$ for all $\chi \in Irr(G)$. Then $N$ must be abelian.

**Proof** Let $\chi \in Irr(G)$. By Clifford's Theorem we have $\chi_N=e\sum_{i=1}^t \vartheta_i$, where $\vartheta_i$'s are the distinct conjugates of a designated irreducible constituent $\vartheta$ of $\chi_N$. Hence $\chi(1)=et\vartheta(1)$ and $\vartheta(1)\mid \chi(1) \mid |G:N|$. But also, $\vartheta(1) \mid |N|$. Since gcd$(|N|,|G:N|)=1$ it follows that all the $\vartheta_i$'s must be linear and hence $N' \subseteq ker(\chi)$. Since $\bigcap_{\chi \in Irr(G)}ker(\chi)=1$, the proposition follows.

Answer (score -1):

Induction on $k:=[G:A]$.  So, assume the result is true for groups which possess abelian normal subgroup of index $<k$ (and satisfy the hypothesis etc.).

Let $\chi=\lambda^G$ for $\lambda$ a linear character of $H_1$. Consider the subgroup $AH_1$.

(1) If $AH_1$ is proper in $G$, then, it contains $A$, and since $\lambda^G$ is irreducible, so $\lambda^{AH_1}$ is irreducible; i.e. $\chi_1=\lambda^{AH_1}$ is monomial character of subgroup $AH_1$ which contains abelian normal subgroup of index less than $[G:A]$, and so apply induction.

(2) Suppose $AH_1=G$. What this implies is that the subgroups $A$ and $H_1$ give single double coset in $G$. So apply Mackey decomposition (Exercise 5.6, Isaacs' book): so 
$$(\lambda^G)_{A}=(\lambda_{A\cap H})^A. $$
Now $A\cap H$ is subgroup of abelian group $A$, so the last character is direct sum of linear characters of $A$ with multiplicity $1$. (This proves the Hint given by Isaacs.)

So restriction of $\chi=\lambda^G$ to $A$ is sum of some irreducible characters of $A$ with multiplicity $1$; apply Clifford's theorem to reach the conclusion.